# Are aakors mythological or copyrighted?

Tags: greek

A friend of mine thinks that an aakor is a creature from the Greek mythology. When I search for "aakor", I see a wiki based on a copyrighted series. I'm not sure if he's correct so I'm asking here.

Are aakors mythological or copyrighted?

Comment: You're friend is wrong. There's no such thing as an "aakor", or a wolf with wings, in greek mythology. https://www.google.com/search?q=aakor+greek+mythology

Answer (score 3):

I can find nothing to suggest the term "aakor" is any older than the role-playing book you've already seen.  I think it would be safe to conclude they made up the name (I don't know if the name is *copyrighted*, per se).

As far as a winged wolf in Greek mythology, none to speak of.  You can find an artifact of the Scythian steppe nomads, though:

[image: Scythian gold plate depicting a winged wolf]

(A couple other sources do refer to this as being a depiction of a winged wolf:  [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3248869?loggedin=true&seq=19#page_scan_tab_contents) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=S9InU-GPNAMC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50#v=onepage&q&f=false), if you have trouble being quite sure of what, exactly, is depicted here, as I do)

The Scythians were certainly not Greeks, but they were concurrent with and known to the Classical Greeks, so not as far flung as it could be, I suppose.